# How to change selected listview item color

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I have this ListView:

```
<Page.Resources>

<DataTemplate x:Key="ListItemTemplate">
    <TextBlock 
        Text="{Binding Name}" 
        Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemStyle}"
        />
```

```
 <ListView 
x:Name="myListView" 
ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListItemTemplate}" 
>
```

How to change the selected listviewitem color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to change the Selected color for the ListViewItem in the ListView, we need to edit its style as following:

Please **right-click the ListView control**->**Edit Additional Templates**->**Edit Generated Item Container(ItemContainerStyle)**->**Edit a Copy**： [image]
Then you will get the following xaml and please modify this **SelectedBackground** property inside the **ListViewItemPresenter** to a color which you like as following：

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ListItemTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle1" TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackground}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemForeground}"/>
        <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
        <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,0,12,0"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMinWidth}"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMinHeight}"/>
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualPrimaryBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemFocusVisualPrimaryBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualPrimaryThickness" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualSecondaryBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemFocusVisualSecondaryBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualSecondaryThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <ListViewItemPresenter CheckBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckBrush}" ContentMargin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" CheckMode="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckMode}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" CheckBoxBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckBoxBrush}" DragForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragForeground}" DragOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}" DragBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragBackground}" DisabledOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}" FocusVisualPrimaryBrush="{TemplateBinding FocusVisualPrimaryBrush}" FocusVisualSecondaryThickness="{TemplateBinding FocusVisualSecondaryThickness}" FocusBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemFocusBorderBrush}" FocusVisualMargin="{TemplateBinding FocusVisualMargin}" FocusVisualPrimaryThickness="{TemplateBinding FocusVisualPrimaryThickness}" FocusSecondaryBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemFocusSecondaryBorderBrush}" FocusVisualSecondaryBrush="{TemplateBinding FocusVisualSecondaryBrush}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True" PointerOverForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemForegroundPointerOver}" PressedBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundPressed}" PlaceholderBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackground}" PointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundPointerOver}" ReorderHintOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" SelectedPressedBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundSelectedPressed}" SelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled}" SelectedForeground="Red" SelectedPointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundSelectedPointerOver}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
SelectedBackground="Red"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListView x:Name="myListView" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListItemTemplate}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle1}"/>
</Grid>
```